# Change image on button click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm new to C# and WP8 Programming, I've designed a simple app with two buttons (next, previous) and an Image (Main_Frame). I've created a folder which contains 24 Images starts from "im2" to "im25". I want the image to be changed on clicking next and previous buttons.

This is what i've tried-

(Xaml)-

```
< Button Content="&lt;---" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,601,0,0" 

VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="Button_Click_1"/>


< Button Content="---&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="379,601,0,0" 

VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" Height="72" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="Button_Click"/>

 < Image x:Name="Main_Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="298" Margin="33,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="393" Source="/Assets/BG.jpg" />
```

(C#)-

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 2; i < 26; i++)
        {
            Main_Frame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Eye_thing/im" + i + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        }


    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i=25; i > 2; i--)
        {
            Main_Frame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Eye_thing/im" + i + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

The loop isn't working and I'm just being forwarded to im2.jpg and im25.jpg on clicking next and previous buttons respectively. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because when you click the button, the full loop is executed. You need to save the current index of the image. Here's an example:

```
private int currentImageIndex = 2; // Initialize this to whichever image number you want

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    if(currentImageIndex < 25) // if not at the last image, increment and set new image
    {
        currentImageIndex++;
        Main_Frame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Eye_thing/im" + currentImageIndex + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(currentImageIndex > 2) // if not at the first image, decrement and set new image
    {
        currentImageIndex--;
        Main_Frame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Eye_thing/im" + currentImageIndex + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that every time you click the button, the *entire* function gets executed. You wanted the code to execute one step out of the loop, but instead it runs the entire loop at once, which is why you are jumped to 2 or 25.

Two steps are needed to fix this. The first - keep the current image saved outside of any of your functions. That is

```
private int currentImage = 2;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
...
```

That means that the value of `currentImage` is saved between executions of the function.

Next, you need to correctly change the value of currentImage every time the button is clicked. That entails two portions - incrementing or decrementing currentImage, and verifying that it is inside your `2 <= currentImage <= 25` bounds.

For example:

```
private int currentImage = 2; //Initialize the value to the minimum image value

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentImage++; //Change currentImage (which is saved outside of the function)
    if(currentImage > 25) //Did increasing the value go over my limit?
    {
        currentImage = 2; //Reset to minimum so it cycles through
    }

    Main_Frame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Eye_thing/im" + currentImage + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentImage--; //Change currentImage (which is saved outside of the function)
    if(currentImage < 2) //Did decreasing the value go over my limit?
    {
        currentImage = 25; //Reset to maximum so it cycles through
    }

    Main_Frame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Eye_thing/im" + currentImage + ".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see why you are using a loop.

you can declare a fiedl variable like an index.

like : `int i = 2;` and a bitmaImage object.

and then each time a button is clicked you increment i by 1 and then you check the value of i and you allocate the image object as you did in your code.
and The samething with the privious button.
YOU ADD SOME if statement. to check if `i >=25` or `i <=2`